# Best way to visualize product's usage given name, start time and end time

Tags: info-visualisation

I have a report which has: Product Name, Start Time, End Time.

```
Amazon DynamoDB 7/1/14 0:00  7/1/14 1:00
Amazon DynamoDB 7/1/14 1:00  7/1/14 2:00
Amazon DynamoDB 7/1/14 4:00  7/1/14 5:00
Amazon DynamoDB 7/1/14 5:00  7/1/14 6:00
Amazon DynamoDB 7/1/14 6:00  7/1/14 7:00
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud    7/1/14 2:00  7/1/14 3:00
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud    7/1/14 3:00  7/1/14 4:00
AWS Data Pipeline   7/1/14 7:00  7/1/14 8:00
AWS Data Pipeline   7/1/14 8:00  7/1/14 9:00
```

I am brainstorming what's the way to visualize a product's usage i.e. which product is mostly used at a particular time. I tried using PowerBi, Tableau and Quicksight.

Comment: are you trying to visualize start and end times in a unit of a day? Are they used for comparison in a sort of schedule? What's the most granular unit to visualize, an hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're viewing usage by a unit of a day**

You can try using a binary heatmap with the hours on the x axis, product labels on the left (instead of the days of the week).

[Here's an example from d3.js:](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084)

[image]

Seems like you're not measuring intensity, just usage or null.

**You can just use one color to represent usage.** The white areas will allow easy contrast for not in use.

You can add a date picker with < > arrows for quick scroll to the next or previous day.